# How to make the entire Angular component clickable

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-components

I have the following template:

```html
<mat-nav-list class="myList">
    <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <my-component-selector class="myItem" [item]="item"></my-component-selector>
    </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

The `my-component-selector` is the selector of `MyComponent` component, which has the following template:

```html
<a class="item-description" routerLink="/details/{{item.getId()}}">{{item.getDescription()}}</a>
<button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteItem(); $event.stopPropagation();"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
```

As you can see, clicking onto the item description redirects me to the details, but I would like to have the entire component be clickable, not just the text.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you move the button inside of the `a`-tag and style it to take the complete available width and height, you should be able to get what you want:

MyComponent template:

```
<a class="item-description" routerLink="/details/{{item.getId()}}">
  {{item.getDescription()}}
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteItem(); $event.stopPropagation();"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
</a>
```

MyComponent CSS

```
::ng-deep my-component-selector{
    display:flex; 
    flex-grow:1;
}
a{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

I've created a quick'n'dirty [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ji7wbg).

Answer (score 2):

you can use click event on the component, it will call the action once you click on the component

```
 <my-component-selector class="myItem" [item]="item" (click)="DoSth($event)"></my-component-selector>
```

Comment: Yeah but I would like to have `MyComponent` to be responsible for handling clicks, and your solution suggests that I handle the click inside of the other component template.

Comment: you should handle the click inside component which contain your Component (my component selector) let us assume that you display this component in home template so you should handle the action in home component ts file

Answer (score 1):

if you want to handle the click in the template. Put a `<div>` in the template and add the click event there